# how to update firebase unique id send by .push to UID from auth

Tags: node.js, firebase-admin

i created a signup function with node js and firebase..here is my script.

```
    var admin = require('./../config/firebase-admin');
    var database = admin.database();
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var _ = require('underscore');
    var fillable = {
        // fbId: "",
        firstName: "",
        middleName: "",
        lastName: "",
        birthdate: "",
        gender: "",
        address: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        password: "",
        imageUrl: "",
        token: "",
        createdAt: "",
        updatedAt: "",

    };
        router.post('/client', (req, res) => {
            var ref = database.ref('clients');


            var body = _.pick(_.assign(fillable, req.body), _.keys(fillable));

            body['createdAt'] = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            ref.push(body);

            res.json(
                        {
                         "messages": [
                           {"text": "You are now registered as Client."}
                         ]
                        }
                    );
        });
```

this works fine.... but when i use `.push` it auto generates the id..

now my question is is there any possibility to update the unique ID that is being generated by the `.push` cause what im trying to make is when the user sign up to page it will save the data to firebase. then once the user use the app and input his/her phone number for authentication the UID will be the unique ID instead of the auto generated ID?. is it possible?.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably implement this as an [update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#update). Updating with a payload like:

```
{
  'old_id': null,
  'new_id': {
    ...
  }
}
```

But I would highly recommend you to reconsider this design. Changing the unique IDs of entries is not a good idea in most systems. See if you can make uid a child attribute of the original entry.

Comment: what i wanted to do is first to insert the data that is being registered from web.. and once the phone number is authenticated the unique id from db will be updated by the UID from authentication. is it possible to do in mobile?.

Comment: The way suggested above is how you would implement a key update. You move the data under `old_id` to `new_id`, and delete the `old_id`. This can be implemented as a single update call.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like the auto generated ID, your next option is to create a unique ID by yourself and save it. However this is risky in my opinion and I see absolutely no reason to do this in your case.

Trying to attempt to change the unique ID is a bad idea, because you are destroying the data relationship (Yes I know it is not like in MySQL etc, but still, we use this ID to uniquely identify users and find related records saved in other tables).